# How to get an object in v-model? Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, customization, vuetify.js, v-model, v-select

I am using `v-autocomplete` to get user's input in a form.

```
<v-autocomplete
       v-model="selected"
       :items="items"
       item-text="short"
       item-value="long"
       chips
       deletable-chips/>
```

The structure of `items` is like this:

```
[
   {
    "long": "item-key",
    "property": [
        {
            "long": "I dont need this",
            "short": "this is what I need"
        }
    ],
    "short": "item-text"
}]
```

and I need to access the `property` field of what user has selected when the key should be `long`. So I was wondering if there is a way that v-model holds the whole object so that I can access the `property` in other parts of the form? If not then what is an alternative way I could use to solve the problem?

I greatly appreciate any help

Comment: You can use `<v-autocomplete return-object ...` and remove `item-value="long" ` From the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#autocomplete),

Comment: Thank you @ljubadr. I use it like this `<div v-for="item in selected.property" >{{item.short}} </div>`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 but there is a problem and that is when I deselect the item that was selected I would still see `{{item.short}}` on the DOM unless I refresh. Should not that be gone since it is in the `v-model`?

Comment: When you clear selection, `this.selected` will be `null`, and your `v-for="item in selected.property"` will throw error. You need to wrap that in `<template v-if="selected"> <div v-for="....">... </div></template>`

Comment: You should probably create computed property: `getSelectedPropertyShort() { return this.selected ? this.selected.property[0].short : ''}`. Not sure which values you will have in your `property` array, but this only works if long/short are first values in the array. And if you have more complex logic, it's easy to add it in this computed property

Comment: @ljubadr `v-if` worked. Do I still need the computed property?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. You don't need computed property if logic is simple enough. Also, keep your devtools open at all times when you develop, as it will help you out to catch errors. And you should install (if you didn't already) [vue devtools extension](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#installation), which helps when working with vue. You can easily inspect your component state `data()` in your devtools, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

No, that would go against the core concept of Vue its self.

Instead, let's use a getter:

```
get selectedItemObject() {
    return this.items.filter(obj => obj.property[0].long === this.selected)
}
```

Psueo code here, make sure to make it type and selector safe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have never seen using a getter before in Vue. Where would I put it? in methods or computed property?

Comment: I might have not been very clear on my question but I dont need the `property[0].long` and the items array could be very long. This is just the structure. Sorry for any confusion on my part. I have updated my question to show which one is the key